# Debugging Django when no Debug info is displayed | Django

Tags: python, django, debugging, iis

**I'm serving an app through IIS6. An error is occurring preventing the app from working, I am not 100% sure what it might be.**

I believe the following is generated by python, but I am not entirely sure.

> **"A server error has occurred. Please contact the administrator"**

---

Any ideas on figuring out what is actually going on?

Comment: in your settings.py is DEBUG = True ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks more like web server error (500?).

Is debugging enabled? You should be able to see exception message and traceback. Also, check web server error log and define [settings.ADMINS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#admins). This is usefull in production when debugging is disabled:

> When DEBUG=False and a view raises an exception, Django will e-mail these people with the full exception information.

Comment: yes DEBUG is set to true and I have added myself to ADMINS too. Thanks for reminding about Web Server logs!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#simple-examples

```
import logging
logging.debug('foobar')
```